# Differentiate an equation

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

I'm learning about implicit differentiation and i'm stuck at understanding the concept of "differentiating an equation".

If I define $ f(x) = x^2$ and $g_1(y) = 9$ and $g_2(y) = 9 + y^2$

Then I define 2 equations:
$(1)$ $f(x) = g_1(y)$ (i.e. $x^2 = 9$)
Then I can't differentiate both side of this equation with respect to x (ortherwise I will get: $2x = 0$)

$(2)$ $f(x) = g_2(y)$ (i.e. $x^2 = 9 + y^2$)
Then I can differentiate both side of this equation with respect to $x$ to get: $ 2.x = 2.y.\frac{dy}{dx}$

Could you please explain me the difference between the 2 cases ? And in general, in which condition could I differentiate both side of an equation concerning more than 1 variable ?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^2=9$ is an equation that has a finite number of real solutions ($2$) for $x$. Differentiating this would not make much sense.

An equation like $x^2-1 = (x-1)(x+1)$ holds true for *all* real $x$. You can differentiate this and both sides will turn out to be equal.

In general, you can differentiate both sides of the equation $f_1(x,y)=f_2(x,y)$ iff this equation holds true for all real $x,y$ in a certain interval of the real numbers, containing infinitely many points.

Comment: Thanks for your response Tavish. I think that the equation $x^2 = 9 - y^2$ is true for all x in the interval (-3,3) but $y$ has to follow $x$ (so not ''all" real $x,y$ in a certain interval). I mean it is true for ''all" $x$ in an interval but not for "all" $y$ in an interval (because $y$ has to follow $x$) Please correct me if i'm wrong somewhere. Thank you very much

Comment: @DucThinhVu That’s true. I don’t mean that independently for all $x,y$ in that interval. Put another way, given any $x$ in an interval, there should be at least one solution for $y$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would like to clarify a little about the concept of "equal function". Say, for example, I have $f_1(x,y)$ = x + y and $f_2(x,y) = x + \sqrt{y}$ and I set up the equation $f_1(x,y) = f_2(x,y)$. But by definition, 2 functions are equal only if their domain (x,y) are equal and the value of the function are equal in that domain. However, the domain of $f_1(x,y)$ is R x R where domain of $f_2(x,y)$ is R x [0, +oo). So why can I setup the equation $f_1(x,y) = f_2(x,y)$ ? Thank you very much

Comment: They are not the same function at all. You are just *setting* their values to be equal, after which you get a curve in $2D$ space containing all points $(x,y)$ for which $f_1=f_2$.

Comment: Thanks for your rapid response. So if they are not "equal", and by your statement, $f_1(x,y)$ and $f_2(x,y)$ must be equal, why could I differentiate the equation $f_1(x,y) = f_2(x,y)$ ? Thank you very much!

Comment: Think of it like this. You can differentiate any equation which represents a curve. $f_1=f_2$ represents a curve in the x-y plane. If $f_1$ and $f_2$ were identical, then we would write $f_1 \equiv f_2$, and that would hold true for every point $(x,y)$ in the plane. Of course, you can still differentiate both sides.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, in this case $f_1(x,y) = f_2(x,y)$ represents a curve in the $x-y$ plane (i.e. a set of points with coordinate $(x,y)$). Then we can only differentiate the equation $f_1(x,y) = f_2(x,y)$ by considering only the point $(x,y)$ that belongs to the curve. Am I right ?

Comment: Of course. If $f_1=f_2$ is true only for certain $(x,y)$, then $f_1’=f_2’$ is also true only for those $(x,y)$.

Comment: oh, thank you very much :p. Can I think of the situation like this: by setting up the equation $f_1(x,y) = f_2(x,y)$, we mean we only care about some part of the curve $f_1(x,y)$ and some part of the curve $f_2(x,y)$ which has equal value. And the slope (w.r.t $x$) of those parts of $f_1(x,y)$ and $f_2(x,y)$ will have same slope (w.r.t $x$). Therefore we can differentiate the equation $f_1(x,y) = f_2(x,y)$ right ?

Comment: Nope. $f_1(x,y)$ is not a curve. It’s just an expression involving $x,y$.

Comment: If a take $f_1(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ then it is a "curve" (i.e. the outer-part of a cauldron). Therefore, I think that $f_1(x,y) = f_2(x,y)$ represent the intersection between the 2 curves $f_1(x,y)$ and $f_2(x,y)$.

Comment: $x^2+y^2$ is not a curve. $z=x^2+y^2$ is a curve in $3d$ space. Their intersection is a curve in $2d$ space.

Comment: Yes. That's what i meant. Thank you very much for your kind help. Happy new year @Tavish

Comment: You’re welcome, happy new year to you as well.

Answer (score 1):

When we write $x^2=9$, $x$ is an unknown, rather than a variable. By contrast, the expression $\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)=2x$ can be viewed as a shorthand for

> Let $f$ be the function defined by $f(x)=x^2$ for all $x$. The function $f'$, evaluated at the arbitrary point $x$, is equal to $2x$, i.e. $f'(x)=2x.$

Here, $x$ is simply a dummy variable used to illustrate what the derivative of the function is. It makes no difference whether we use $x$ or $y$ or any other  variable. So $x$ is being used in two different ways here, hence why contradictory results appear.

By contrast, the second example, $x^2=9+y^2$, does show a relationship between the variables $x$ and $y$. Again, this could be expressed more formally as

> Let $y$ be an arbitrary function satisfying $y(x)^2+9=x^2$ for all $x$.

When we differentiate both sides with respect to $x$, what we are doing is showing that $y'(x)$ must satisfy the following property:

> $2x=2y(x)y'(x) \, .$

Even though we might not have an explicit formula about $y$, implicit differentiation allows us to make meaningful statements about this function.

Answer (score 0):

A few notes: you are taking derivatives.  I think the more fundamental operator is the differential (which gets confusing because taking a derivative is referred to as "differentiating").  The differential is like a derivative, but not with respect to any variable.  So, for instance the derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$ but the differential is $2x\,dx$.  The derivative of $xy$ depends on which variable the derivative is being taken with respect to, but the differential is just $x\,dy + y\,dx$.

Derivatives are more likely to lead to contradictions.  For instance, take the equation $x = 1$.  The derivative of this with respect to $x$ is $1 = 0$.  However, the differential is $dx = 0$, which is true: the value of $x$ is not changing.  The reason for the contradiction of the derivative is that the derivative with respect to $x$ is just the differential divided by $dx$.  Since $dx = 0$, dividing both sides by $0$ leads to an invalid $\frac{0}{0}$.

So, going back to your problem, when you had $x^2 = 9$, the differential gives you a better picture. $2x\,dx = 0$.  Why?  Because at $x^2 = 9$, $x$ is *not moving*, so the differential is zero.  If you try to *divide* by $dx$, you will wind up with an invalid $\frac{0}{0}$.

So, in your second case, differentiating gives you: $2x\,dx = 2y\,dy$.  You can then solve for the derivative by algebraic manipulations.

So, in both cases, finding the differential works.  In the first case, finding the derivative doesn't work because you wind up with a $\frac{0}{0}$ when you try.